# Runtime permissions: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=123, result=0, data=null} to activity

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I am trying to get READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Here is my code

```
    // Check if user granted the permission
    int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


   if(hasReadExternalStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       displaySongs();
   } else {
       // Should we show explanation?
        if( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
               // Show explanation to user
        } else {

            // No explanation needed. We can request permissions
            String permissions[] = {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
   }
```

Here is the call back method

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                displaySongs();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

- I am debugging my application on Nexus 6P.
- Target and compiled SDK version is 24.
- When I run the app, It does not show any Permission prompt. It just crashes.

This is the error message that I get in my Android Monitor

```
    09-27 20:05:48.143 31106-31106/org.javacad.music E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: org.javacad.music, PID: 31106
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=123, result=0, data=null} to activity {org.javacad.music/org.javacad.music.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                   at org.javacad.music.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:129)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

- I did not check "Never ask again" check box.
- I did not deny the permission request.
- I already defined permission as direct child of manifest element in AndoridManifest.xml

  ```
   <!--READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION to read files form storage-->
  <user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```

  - Why permission dialog box is not showing up?
  - Why I am getting empty permissions and grantResults array in call back method?

Comment: It's `uses-permission`, not `user-permission`. You have a typo in your manifest permission element.

Comment: My bad. It works, Thank you

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this exception occurred since I was trying to show fragment immediately inside `onRequestPermissionsResult`. Adding delay fixed the problem.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQ_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           showFragment(QRCodeFragment.newInstance()); //Fragment transaction code 
                       }
                   }, 500);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant camera permission to use the QR Scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is genius.  It would have taken me a long time to figure out that this particular error message was caused by the fragment attempting to show too quickly on API 23.

Comment: @NightFury Wtf, I never would have thought of this! But why does it work? The Dialog should be displayed before this method is called, shouldn't it? So why does a delay fix this?